# Pandas: How to make new df based on multiple record values from original df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to focus on specific values from a dataframe within a specific column to create a new dataframe with a new column with those specific values

I tried to do the following, but it only works with 1 parameter.

Any insight would be extremely helpful

```
new_df = df[df.ethnicity == 'white','asian','latin']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pandas [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) method:

```py
new_df = df[df.ethnicity.isin(['white','asian','latin'])]
```